# After using astype to convert from object to int, value counts changed?

Tags: python, pandas

I was using astype to convert a df.column from object to int type. However, after I used it, the value_counts() of each value changed dramatically shown below. Would anyone know the cause for this?

**Before** 
2   :    515220 
3    :   402506 
1     :  322136 
4      : 235173 
5       :152411

**After**
2 :     543368
3  :    424678
1   :   339239
4    :  247637
5     : 160653

Comment: It will be difficult to help without some sample data to reproduce.

Comment: Please add some sample data, and maybe the output of `df.column.unique()`